# Using plyr to run GLMM's on large dataset

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to run a series of GLMM's on a large dataset to explore relationships between plant traits and environmental factors for each of several plant species at different research sites using plots and years as random factors in my models. I'm using `plyr` and I keep getting the following error message:

> Error in eval.quoted(.variables, data) : 
>     envir must be either NULL, a list, or an environment.

My data set is in the following format:

```
   Site    Plot   Species  FlowerDate  Year     Factor   FactorValue
1    AD   ADC01     CTETB         179  1999   numJulSF           160
```

And here is the code I am using:

```
data.list <- dlply(data,c("Species","Site","FlowerDate","Year", "Factor"), 
                   function(df){lmer(FlowerDate~FactorValue+(1|Plot)+(1|Year), 
                                data=df)})
```

I have seen that others have this issue, but I'm still having difficulty resolving it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the main problem is that you are splitting the data based on some of the variables that are actually included in the model ('FlowerData' and 'Year'), which does not make sense in principle (no point in including an input variable that does not variable, or modeling an output variable that is constant).

Other than that, the combination of dlply + lmer should work; in fact, I use it quite often without problems...